# Slowness while drawing on PictureBox in Windows 10

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-10, drawing, picturebox

I have a WinForm application which has one of the forms used to draw/scribble on a PictureBox. The application is working fine on `Windows 7` and `Windows 8`. But recently when I tried it on `Windows 10`, I feel too much slowness when drawing on a PictureBox. Slowness means it is not catching up with the pointer position and it is always lagging behind and catch up later on.

Following is the layout of the form which has PictureBox in it:

> Form -> TableLayoutPanel -> Panel -> PictureBox

I am getting the Graphics object of PictureBox's image and drawing using that graphics object. I am not using the Paint event for drawing. After each scribble I reset the PictureBox's image.

It can be possible that I have to apply a different approach for proper drawing, but my question is why the same logic is working perfectly fine on `Windows 7` and `Windows 8` and have worse performance on `Windows 10`.

Comment: Add a stopwatch to check how much time it takes to paint the image? It must be so slow (>100 ms for a paint) for you to perceive this slowness. As for why it just doesn't work on Windows 10 that I can only think of some reason like "the display driver is not installed at all", try another Windows 10 device if you have.

Comment: @kennyzx the slowness is very noticeable that it can be easily seen while scribbling. I have tested it on 5 different windows 10 machines and all have the same behavior. I will double check the display driver installation.

Comment: then I don't think it has anything to do with display driver. you will need to spend some time to provide an MCVE for us to debug.

Comment: The first thing you do is testing your proc painting properly on the Control. Use the Paint event, that is, not `Control.CreateGraphics()`. Also, your PictureBox should probably be a Custom Control, because you might want to activate some of its *EX* styles, such as `OptimizedDoubleBuffer` and `UserPaint`. If you don't, painting on a PictureBox or a Panel when an Image is already set in the background, causes the same *effect* in Windows 7.